# Basic exercise about distribution theory

Tags: proof-verification, distribution-theory

> $\textbf{Exercise.}$ Let be $u \in \mathfrak{D}'(\Omega)$ and $\varphi \in \mathfrak{D}$ such that $\varphi|_{\text{supp} \ u} \equiv 0$. Is it true that $\varphi u \equiv 0$?

It seems obviously true that $\varphi u \equiv 0$, but I would like to check my attempt because this exercise seems extremely simple to be an exercise. If I'm wrong, I would like a hint in order to construct a counterexample because I can't see how $\varphi u \neq 0$ in these hypothesis.

What I thought is pretty simple:

Case $1$ - $x \in \text{supp} \ u$:

$(\varphi u) (x) = \varphi(x) u(x) = 0 u(x) = 0$.

Case $2$ - $x \notin \text{supp} \ u$:

$(\varphi u) (x) = \varphi(x) u(x) = \varphi(x) 0 = 0$,

therefore $\varphi u \equiv 0$. $\square$

Comment: Look at $\delta'$. $\quad \varphi$ and **all its derivatives** vanish on $supp\ u$ implies $<u,\varphi> = 0$ (the proof is : take a sequence $\varphi_n \to \varphi \in C^\infty_c$ with $\varphi_n$ supported on the complementary of $supp\ u$).

Comment: The problem with this proof is that $u(x)$ has no meaning. You'll have to treat it fully as a distribution.

Comment: @NinadMunshi, so what means $\varphi u$? Is it would be $\langle \varphi, u \rangle$, where $\langle \varphi, u \rangle = \int_{\Omega} f_u(x) \varphi(x) dx$ and the $f_u$ would be a function associated to the distribution $u$?

Comment: @Mathenthusiast that's only true for some distributions that have a continuous function kernel. That is certainly not true for all distributions, but it certainly motivates the definition for general smooth function + distribution multiplication, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $\phi\in\mathcal{D}$. Then by definition of multiplication of smooth function and distribution:

$$\varphi u(\phi) \equiv u(\varphi \phi)$$

Can you take it from here, using the definition of $\text{Supp}(u)$?

Comment: What do you get with $u = \delta', \varphi=x$

Comment: @reuns  $x\delta'(\phi) \equiv \delta'(x\phi(x)) = -(x\phi(x))'\Bigr|_{x=0} = (-\phi(x) - x\phi'(x))\Bigr|_{x=0} = -\phi(0) \implies x\delta' = -\delta$, a classical result...

Comment: Sure but why your answer isn't about this

Comment: @reuns why would it be? OP should see the subtlety of the definition of $\text{Supp}(u)$. Having just one counterexample doesn't necessarily explain why an object behaves differently from the way we expect.

Comment: To show that if all the derivatives of $\varphi$ vanish on $supp(u)$ then $<u,\varphi>=0$ I think we should look at $\phi\in C^\infty_c[-1,1],\int\phi=1,\Psi_n= n \phi(n.) \ast 1_{dist(x,supp(u))< 2/n} \in C^\infty$ (which is constant $=1$ on $dist(x,supp(u))< 1/n$ and constant $=0$ on $dist(x,supp(u))> 3/n$) then $\varphi(1-\Psi_n)\to \varphi$ in $C^\infty_c$ so that $<u,\varphi> =\lim_{n \to \infty}<u,\varphi(1-\Psi_n)> =0$

Comment: @NinadMunshi, I'm using the notion of support of a distribution given in the observation $1.54$ of [this](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~stein/lehre/SoSem09/distrvo.pdf) lecture notes.

$\mathbb{R}^n \backslash \text{supp} \ (\varphi u(\phi)) \subset \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \text{supp} \ (u(\varphi \phi))$:

let be $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \text{supp} \ (\varphi u(\phi))$. There is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $\varphi u(\phi)|_U \equiv 0$, then $u(\varphi \phi)|_U = \varphi u(\phi)|_U \equiv 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \text{supp} \ (u(\varphi \phi))$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n \backslash \text{supp} \ (\varphi u(\phi)) \supset \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \text{supp} \ (u(\varphi \phi))$:

let be $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \text{supp} \ (u(\varphi \phi))$. There is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $\varphi u(\varphi \phi)|_U \equiv 0$, then $\varphi u(\phi)|_U = u(\varphi \phi)|_U \equiv 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \text{supp} \ (\varphi u(\phi))$